# Why is temporary storage needed in sorting array?

Tags: c

The piece of code was :

```
if(a[i] > a[j]){
   temp = a[i];
   a[i] = a[j];
   a[j] = temp;
}
```

Why a temp variable has to be used ? When I try without temp :

```
if(a[i] > a[j]){  
   a[i] = a[j];
}
```

it wont work, but before it was working when I compare other variables

Comment: Because you are overwriting the initial value of `a[i]` so you don't know what to assign `a[j]`

Comment: What happens to the old value of `a[i]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have this temp variable

```
temp = a[i];
a[i] = a[j];
a[j] = temp;
```

then you will lose the value that was in `a[i]` (previous to the assignment `a[i] = a[j]`.

There is a way to swap values without having the using a temporal value. The solution is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

In C is like this:

```
int x = 10, y = 5;
// Code to swap 'x' (1010) and 'y' (0101)
x = x ^ y;  // x now becomes 15 (1111)
y = x ^ y;  // y becomes 10 (1010)
x = x ^ y;  // x becomes 5 (0101)
```

Using the XOR operator. Code is from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-two-numbers-without-using-temporary-variable/), go to that link to find the entire explanation and possible drawbacks of using this solution.

Comment: I knew there was a way to swap them without a temp variable, I was just too slow to find it, lol. +1 when my votes comes back.

Comment: There are various reasons not to use the XOR swap.  On modern architectures, the XOR swap is often slower than using a temporary, particularly with pipelining processors.  Modern compilers can often optimise away the temporary (by use of machine registers) anyway, and it is harder to do that with sequential XOR as the results of each statement depend on the previous ones.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment is a one way operation. `a = b` only assigns the value of `b` to `a`. Once this assignment is done, the original value of `a` is lost, so there is no way to assign that value to `b`.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
a[i] = a[j]
```

copies what is `a[j]` to `a[i]`, the previous content of `a[i]` is lost.

that is why you need to save that in order to swap the information.

it is the same as if

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

b = a;  // now contents of b is gone and cannot be assigned to a
```

Answer (score 2):

An assignment  `a = b` copies the value of `b` into the variable `a`.  It does not swap them, and loses/discards the original value of `a`.

Since you don't want to lose either original value (doing so would mean you are not swapping), it is necessary to hold one of the values somewhere else while doing the assignments.   That is the function of the temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int main(void) {
  int a = 2, b = 5, c = 7, d = 11, temp = 0;

  /* a gets overwritten before it was swapped */
  a = b; // a is overwritten and becomes 5 (same value as b)
  b = a; // b becomes 5 (same value as a, which is already same as b)
  printf("%d %d", a, b); // this will print out 5 5
  /* you can see that we lost value of a because it was overwritten */


  /* c gets stored in temporary value before it was stored */
  temp = c;  // temp becomes 7
  c = d;     // c is overwritten with 11 (same value as d
  d = temp;  // d is overwritten with 7 (same as temp or original c)

  return 0;
}
```